# Nativescript and images orientation

Tags: nativescript

I'm using nativescript v.4.2 along with "@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus": "^2.0.2".

I have a generic code that is copied from the camera plugin repository demo page. I'm not posting my code, as the problem is different - I don't have problems with image grabbing etc, but I've noticed that the plugin has issues with screen orientation. If you start a page with portrait mode and rotate the device, the camera is smaller and looks like a bug.
So i've removed option to rotate a device in info.plist by removing:

```xml
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

Now the camera is looking good, you can rotate the device and you will not end up with issues with the size of the camera - it has 100% of width and height always.

The problem is, that even if are making a shot with a device set in the landscape, the result image is rotated 90% clockwise as the result.
Attached below a.jpg and b.jpg - a.jpg shows the camera with take a photo button and b.jpg shows the result image. Everything is ok when you're doing a photo in portrait mode, but it's not the case in landscape.

My question is - do you suspect that the camera plugin may have an issue? Or it's related to nativescript?

I see that nativescript orientation plugin is working well, I mean when I'm doing a photo I can get information, on what mode the photo was made:

```js
    var orientation = require('nativescript-orientation');
    console.log(orientation.getOrientation());
```

If now I could edit this image somehow and rotate it properly...

This is a page that is rendered when an image is made (IMG is a path from Localstorage that is created on the previous page)

Review page:

```js
<Page class="page" loaded="loaded" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:Gradient="nativescript-gradient" xmlns:header="components/header">
    <ScrollView  height="100%" class="scrollview" scrollBarIndicatorVisible="false">
        <StackLayout class="with-bottomnav" style="padding: 0">
            <GridLayout  rows="*" columns="40,*,40" class="zindex"  width="100%" height="100" top="30" padding="0 20">
                <Image col="0" src="{{ controls }}" tap="{{ action }}" stretch="none" class="menu" />
                <Image col="1" src="{{ headerLogo }}" horizontalAlignment="center" class="logo" horizontalAlignment="center"  />
                <Image col="2" src="{{ user }}" horizontalAlignment="right" class="user" verticalAlignment="top" />
            </GridLayout>
            <Image src="{{ IMG }}" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="center" id="Image" class="{{ exif == landscape ? 'dynamic' : 'dynamic-rotate' }}"></Image>
            <StackLayout left="0"  class="zindex"  horizontalAlignment="center">
                <Label class="info" text="Does this photo look ok to you ?" color="white"></Label>

                <StackLayout  class="footer white" verticalAlignment="bottom"  width="100%"  padding="0 20">
                    <Gradient:Gradient direction="to right" colors="#e41d8d, #ffa249" class="button login" tap="{{ perfect }}">
                        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="70,*">
                            <Label row="0" col="0"  marginLeft="30" class="allow" />
                            <Label row="0" col="1" text="Perfect" horizontalAlignment="center" marginLeft="-70" />
                        </GridLayout>
                    </Gradient:Gradient>
                    <StackLayout class="button bordered login white" tap="{{ tryAgian }}">
                        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="70,*">
                            <Label row="0" col="0"  marginLeft="30" class="deny" />
                            <Label row="0" col="1" text="Let Me try again" horizontalAlignment="center" marginLeft="-70" />
                        </GridLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

The code for the camera page. Image is made, and some variables saved, then I redirect to the review page - the code above shows the view file ...

```js
    model.photo = function (args) {
        var orientation = require('nativescript-orientation');
        // Get orientation of device
        console.log(orientation.getOrientation());
      var cam = page.getViewById("camPlus");
        //cam.toggleCamera();
        cam.requestCameraPermissions().then(function () {
            if (!cam) {
                cam = new CameraPlus();
            }
            cam.takePicture({ saveToGallery: false });
        });
        cam.on(CameraPlus.photoCapturedEvent, function(args) {
            console.log('Event captured');
            var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
            var path = fs.path.join(documents.path, "AppPic.png");
            var resultImage;
            var source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
            source.fromAsset(args.data).then(function (res) {
                // get width and height - i think i will use those and if image is made on landscape i will reverse width and height <- Hack :(
                console.dir(res.width);
                console.dir(res.height);
                resultImage = res;
                var folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
                var mixedDate = Date.now();
                LS.setItem('Path-Avatar-Name',mixedDate);
                // Save orientation, if landscape i will add css (transform:rotate(-90deg)) <- Hack :(
                LS.setItem('Path-Avatar-Exif',orientation.getOrientation())
                // Save some image stuff like path or name
                var path = fs.path.join(folder.path, 'IMG'+ mixedDate + ".jpeg");
                LS.setItem('Path-Avatar-Ext',".jpeg");
                var saved = res.saveToFile(path, "jpeg");
                console.log(path);
                console.log(saved);
                LS.setItem('Path-Avatar',path);
                //resultImage.saveToFile(path, "png");
                //var x = res.toBase64String('jpeg');
            }).then(function() {
                if (LS.getItem('DocumentType') == 'passport') {
                    //goToPage('take/review/review')
                }
                //goToPage('dashboard/dashboard/dashboard')
            });
        })

        // Go to review page 
        goToPage('take/review/review')*/
    };
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your page / layout? Are you facing this only with iOS?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. The code for review page is added, and also javascript for page that is used to make a photo .

Comment: I think you shouldn't be using ScrollView, if you just want the image to fit in on the screen then simply use a GridLayout with image in it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but when i'm saving this image into API, it's rotated to. so i have double trouble now ...:)

Comment: Do you have sample repo which I can use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I will prepare one.Thanks.